# How to formulate this in gurobi

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, gurobi

I have subtour elimination constraint but can't understand and formulate this in gurobipy. How to formulate this ?

$$
\sum_{i \in S} \sum_{j \in S} x_{i j}^{v} \leq|S|-1 \quad v=1, \ldots, m ; S \subseteq V-\{0\}
$$

Comment: Can you be more specific about where you are stuck. Is it the part about iterating over all subsets $S$ of $V\backslash \lbrace 0 \rbrace?$

Comment: Thanks for the response @prubin, yeah you are right, i'm stuck with the subset of S

Comment: @overboxed, would you see this link from Gurobi [tsp.py](https://colab.research.google.com/github/Gurobi/modeling-examples/blob/master/traveling_salesman/tsp_gcl.ipynb) example?

Comment: @A.Omidi Thank you, i will check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that $\hat{V}=V\backslash \lbrace 0 \rbrace =\lbrace 1,\dots,m\rbrace$ for some integer $m.$ If $\hat{V}$ is something else, you'll need to map the elements of $\hat{V}$ (in any arbitrary order) to $1,\dots,m.$

There are $2^m$ subsets of $\hat{V},$ including the empty set. Each subset $S$ is associated with a characteristic vector $z\in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^m$ where $z_i=1$ if and only if $i\in S.$ Each characteristic vector in turn can be assigned a unique integer index $\sum_{i=1}^m 2^{z_i}.$

So to iterate over the subsets, you can iterate over the integers $1,\dots, 2^m.$ For each integer in that range, express it as a binary vector and include in $S$ the integers in $\lbrace 1,\dots,m\rbrace$ corresponding to the locations of the 1 bits.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but what is really the meaninf of subset of S? I don't really quite understand from the point of view of this constraint, let alone the code.

Comment: A subtour is a tour (Hamiltonian circuit, loop) that visits some subset $S$ of the set $V$ of all vertices but does not include the start / depot / origin node 0. To prevent a subtour using the nodes in $S$, you require that the number of arcs within $S$ that are crossed be less than the number of vertices in $S$. So if $S=\lbrace 3, 5, 8\rbrace,$ to prevent a subtour like $3\rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 5 \rightarrow 3$ you add a constraint saying that at most two of the arcs $(3,5), (5,3), (3,8), (8,3), (5,8), (8,5)$ are crossed.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer, sir.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Python, look into the itertools package. To create the powerset (minus the empty set), we can do:

```
from itertools import chain,combinations

n = 4 
s = range(1,n+1)
list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(1,len(s)+1)))
```

which produces:

```
[(1,),
 (2,),
 (3,),
 (4,),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 4),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 3, 4),
 (2, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: how to apply this over the constraint?

Comment: That should be rather obvious, no?

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but i'm quite new in OR and python. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: You can loop over this list. This is getting close to explaining what a '+' is.